# Google SERP not showing my metatags OR auto-generated ones

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, meta-description

I manage a multilingual e-commerce Drupal website which is now included in Google's index, but Google SERPs show URL and page title but no text at all where the meta description (or auto-generated alternative) should be shown.

You can see what I mean here:

[image]

- Metatag descriptions of the recommended length are present on every page, carefully-crafted: useful, relevant and  unique (non-pasted) text
- Metatags or auto-generated alternatives are shown as expected in all the other search engines I've looked at (Yahoo, AOL, Bing, Duckduckgo) and indeed are visible to online tools "meta tag checker" type tools like [this](https://seositecheckup.com/) and [this](https://totheweb.com/learning_center/tool-test-google-title-meta-description-lengths/)

Answer (score 1):

If you open the kebab menu (the three vertical dots on the SERP) you will see that none of your pages have been *cached* yet by Google. You say that your website was only recently indexed; Google needs time in order to cache your pages and properly generate snippet descriptions.

The solution is to wait for Google to catch up. Give it a week or so and the descriptions should start looking more populated.

In fact, if I refresh the search results a few times, it already shows me a description *some* of the time:

[image: search result with snippet]

The rest of the time I get a result like in your screenshot, without a description. So that means that the description for your home page is already being served up by *some* of Google's request fulfillment servers - give it time and it be available on all of them and be served to all Google search users!

Comment: Thank you Maximillian. Makes sense. The site's been up since February, the only significant change i made this week was to request a removal of the dev environment from Google's index - could that have been the reason ?

Comment: @TomFallowfield Probably not, unless you accidentally requested cache removal for pages on the production domain. Perhaps the site only recently had enough backlinks to be indexed.